# UITableView scrolls down when contentInset is set and UITextField in tableViewHeader becomes active

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, xcode6

**Problem**

I'm trying too make a *custom* search text field, added to a UITableViewController, always stick to the top of the page.
Like this:

[image]

Everything works fine, but when I tap the search text field to becomeFirstResponder the tableView strangely scrolls down.

[image]

I have discovered that this *only* happens when I manually setts the contentInset for the UITableView. (So that the tableview section headers don't hides behind the search view)

**How I have built it**

*Layers:*

- TableView

  - UIView (as UITableView.tableViewHeaderView)
  - UIView (to update the frame when the user scrolling the tableView)

    - UITextField (for search input)

*Code for fixing the search view frame when user scrolls:*

```
var rect = frame
rect.origin.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y + 64
frame = rect
```

I may be doing everything stupid, but I would like to have the view stick to the top, because the user will use search more than other apps. Any ideas?

My app requires iOS 8 so I have not been available to test this on iOS 7. I can make a screen recording if that helps.

**UPDATE**
I've created an example project with the same objects I'm using in my main project.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qdlx0milebbuf3p/Search%20bug%20Example.zip?dl=0

Comment: Just a doubt Why do you want to add the searchBar inside tableView if you dont want it to scroll?

Comment: I need to use a UITableViewController for the extra features, like UIRefreshControl and more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a UIKit bug. To fix this I've created a subclass for `UITableView` to **NEVER** change the content offset when `isScrollEnabled` is `NO`.

.h

```
@interface CUISearchTableView : UITableView

@end
```

.m

```
#import "CUISearchTableView.h"

@implementation CUISearchTableView

- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    if (self.isScrollEnabled) {
        [super setContentOffset:contentOffset];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you need to do all that.  If you'd just use a UIViewController and add a UITableView to that, then you could place the UISearchView anywhere ( i.e., the top of the view ).  You just need to make sure that the UISearchView is the top-most view ( bring subview to front ).

I get that you're using a UITableViewController, but if you want to use your own search view instead of the TableViewController+Search then this is your best bet.  The only thing that would be necessary is adding the top content offset ( which you're already doing ).  you could then just delete the CUISearchTableView.

Does this make sense or am I missing something?